# TaskScheduler do not run task on main thread

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I write following code to try using TaskScheduler. Task content within the `UpdateStatus` function need to be run on the main thread. But I just get the output indicate that it's running on separate thread.

Any ideas about the reason? or alternative method of writing status from background thread in main thread context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Test
  {
    TaskScheduler scheduler;
    public void Run()
    {
      SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
      scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
      Console.WriteLine("Start on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("running on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
          UpdateStatus(string.Format("Message {0}", i));
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
      }).ContinueWith(_ =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine("complate");
        Console.WriteLine("running on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      }, new CancellationToken(), TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler).Wait();
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string message)
    {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine("updating status on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
      }, new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var test = new Test();
      test.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly does the code need to run on the main thread? `Console` is thread-safe, so you can use that from any thread.

Comment: A console mode app doesn't have a synchronization provider that's capable of running code on a specific thread.  That's in general a very nontrivial thing to do, it requires the target thread to cooperate.  It must provide a solution to the [producer/consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  Like any GUI app does.  Otherwise known as "pumping the message loop".

Comment: @svick This is just a demo of my problem, in fact I'm writing powershell cmdlet, in which `WriteObject` do need to be within a certain context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explain what exactly are you trying to do, so it's hard to advise you on the best course of action.

Your current code doesn't work, because the `SynchronizationContext` you're creating doesn't actually do any synchronization. (And your main thread is also blocked on the `Wait()` call, so nothing else can run on it.)

You *could* use synchronization context that synchronizes properly to the main thread (like [the one from Nito AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext)), but I'm not sure that's the best way in your case.

I think a better approach would be to use the producer/consumer pattern using `BlockingCollection`. Your `Task`s would add items to it and your main thread would take them from there and send them to the pipeline using `WriteObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

The Default SynchronizationContext (which you are using), doesn't get you to the main thread.  See [Why SynchronizationContext does not work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892453/why-synchronizationcontext-does-not-work-properly).

As svick mentions, in your case (a Console application), there is usually no need for the concept of a main thread.