# Tasks - how to ensure the ContinueWith action is an STA thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to use [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a little .net 4.0 application (written using Visual Studio 2010 if that matters) that needs to work on Windows 2003 and use a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346378%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the palette parameter.

The code using said class **must**, therefore, be running as an STA thread to avoid it throwing an [invalid cast exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31a25e7d-6ef1-433f-9e38-d85a19ea0172/writeablebitmap-constructor-raises-exception-when-used-within-nunit?forum=wpf) for why I need an STA thread if you are interested, but it is not the thrust of my question).

I, therefore, checked on Stack overflow and came across [How to create a task (TPL) running a STA thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971686/1039947) and [The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245926/1039947) - perfect, so now I know what to do, except...

Here's a little console application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace TaskPlayingConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before Anything: " 
                + Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState());

            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                new SynchronizationContext());
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => Console.WriteLine(
                    "In task: " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()),
                cts.Token,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                scheduler);

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
                 Console.WriteLine(
                   "In continue: " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()),
                   scheduler);

            task.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is its output:

```
Before Anything: STA 
In task: STA 
In continue: MTA
```

What the!?!  Yup, it is back to an **MTA** thread on the `Action<Task>` passed into the `ContinueWith` method.

I am passing the *same* scheduler into the task and the continue but somehow in the continue it seems to be being ignored.

I'm sure it is something stupid, so how would I make sure that my callback passed into the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321307%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses an STA thread?

Comment: I was going to automatically write that you've probably forgot to specify the scheduler, but all of that is in place.. strange.

Comment: Those results are strange and I get different results. I would expect 'In task' to return MTA (and it does for me) because the default implementation of `SynchronizationContext` uses the .NET ThreadPool. ThreadPool threads are MTA by default.

Comment: @mikez: yes, that suprised me too. That's why I think that first task was run synchronously right at the moment when StartNew was issued, but I can't think of why it was at all and why later ContinueWith was not treated in the same way..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: before you read any of the following, here's an excellent on-topic article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx ; You can skip my post and go directly there!

Most important part describing the root cause:

> The **default implementation** of SynchronizationContext.Post just turns around and **passes it off to the ThreadPool** via QueueUserWorkItem. But (...) can derive their own context from SynchronizationContext and override the Post method to be more appropriate to the scheduler being represented.
>
> In the case of Windows Forms, for example, the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext implements Post to pass the delegate off to Control.BeginInvoke. For DispatcherSynchronizationContext in WPF, it calls to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. And so on.

So, you need to use something other than the base SynchronizationContext class. Try using any of the other existing ones, or create your own. Example is included in the article.

---

And now, my original response:

After thinking a bit, I think the problem is that in your console application there is no thing like "message pump". The default SynchronizationContext is just a piece of lock. It prevents threads from intersecting on a resource, but it does not provide any queueing or thread selection. In general you are **meant to** subclass the SynchroContext to provide your own way of proper synchronization. Both WPF and WinForms provide their own subtypes.

When you `Wait` on your task, most probably the MainThread gets blocked and all other are run on some random threads from the default threadpool.

Please try writing Thread IDs to the console along with the STA/MTA flag.

You will probably see:

```
STA: 1111
STA: 1111
MTA: 1234
```

If you see this, then most probably your **first task** is run **synchronously** on the calling thread and gets instantly finished, then you try to "continue" it's just 'appended' to 'the queue', but it is not started immediatelly (guessing, I dont know why so; the old task is finished, so ContinueWith could also just run it synchronously). Then main thread gets locked on wait, and since there's no message pump - it cannot switch to another job and sleeps. Then threadpool waits and sweps the lingering continuation task. Just guessing though. You could try to check this by

```
prepare synccontext
write "starting task1"
start task1 ( -> write "task1")
write "continuing task2"         <--- add this one 
continue: task2 ( -> write "task2")
wait
```

and check the order of messages in the log. Is "continuing" before "hello" from task1 or not?

You may also try seeing what happens if you don't create the Task1 by StartNew, but rather create it as prepared/suspended, then Continue, then start, then wait. If I'm right about the synchronous run, then in such setup main and continuation task will either both be run on the calling '1111' STA thread, or both on threadpool's '2222' thread.

Again, if all of these is right, the providing some message pump and proper SyncContext type will probably solve your issue. As I said, both WPF and WinForms provide their own subtypes. Although I don't remember the names now, you can try using them. If I remember correctly, the WPF starts its dispatcher automatically and you don't need any extra setup. I don't remember how's with WinForms. But, with the WPF's auto-start, if your ConsoleApp is actually some kind of a unit-test that will run many separate cases, you will **need** to shutdown the WPF's dispatcher before the cases.. but that's far from the topic now.

Comment: I think you are bang on - I put in the extra messages and, indeed, the first two entries are on the same thread.  OK, so then I need to do some more research on this SynchroContext thing...thanks!

Comment: See this answer, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14144101/717732 although it's a bit different question in overall, the issues described there are similar

Comment: Ah, here it is finally http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx

Comment: I suggest that you include the important points in the linked article to more clearly answer the question. E.g. like this quote: _But there’s one common kind of application that doesn’t have a SynchronizationContext: console apps. When your console application’s Main method is invoked, SynchronizationContext.Current will return null. That means that if you invoke an asynchronous method in your console app, unless you do something special, your asynchronous methods will not have thread affinity: the continuations within those asynchronous methods could end up running “anywhere.”_

Comment: Thanks very much - based on this and the linked article I made my own little SynchronizationContext and hooked that instead and made sure that everything's called on the same thread, which is good enough for my console application!

Comment: @MartinLiversage: This is important piece, but please note that kmp has already `SetSynchronizationContext`, so the `Current` is certainly not null at the point of creating and starting the first task. The article is filled with important bits. I didn't know wht to quote.. The core point was that the default base `SynchroContext` class is **far less usable** than anyone would think when seeing it for the first time. But you're right. I'll include the quote about it here, just in case the target article evaporates.

Comment: @kmp could you post your 'little SynchronizationContext' class here please :-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - I used this in a unit test I wrote for a library I stuck up on github a while back - have a look at the inner class [SingleThreadSynchronizationContext](https://github.com/kmp1/nsane/blob/master/test/ScanTest.cs) in the [nsane](https://github.com/kmp1/nsane) repository.